# Json Data assign to java class

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm having problem to assign json data into java class.Please do help anyone,
My java class is like,

```
public class ListofGridRecords<T> {
    public int Totalrecords;
    public List<T> GridRecords;//using TraderTransaction class.
}
```

and TraderTransaction class is,

```
public class TraderTransaction {

  public Date AddedTime;
  public String TransactId;
  public TransactStatus Status;
  public String OtherPartyAccountNo;
  public Double AmountPaid;
  public Double AmountRecieved;
  public Double ClosingBalance;
  public TransactionTypes TransType;
  public String Narration;

  public TraderTransaction() {
    super();
  }
}
```

and my json conversion function look like,

```
JsonObject returndata = JsonObject.parse(responseString);
String operationresult = returndata.get("OperationResult").toString();

if (Result.values()[Integer.parseInt(operationresult)] == Result.Success) {
  Gson gson = new Gson();

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  ListofGridRecords<TraderTransaction> traderlist = 
        gson.fromJson(returndata.get("ResultData").toString(), ListofGridRecords.class);

  Log.i("LIST DATA:", "" + traderlist);
  for (TraderTransaction trader: traderlist.GridRecords) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(TRANS_FIRST_COLUMN, currentformatter.format(trader.AddedTime));
    map.put(TRANS_SECOND_COLUMN, trader.TransactId);
    map.put(TRANS_THIRD_COLUMN, trader.OtherPartyAccountNo);
    map.put(TRANS_FOURTH_COLUMN, trader.AmountPaid.toString());
    map.put(TRANS_FIFTH_COLUMN, trader.AmountRecieved.toString());
    map.put(TRANS_SIXTH_COLUMN, OpenOrClosed.values()[Integer.parseInt(trader.TransType.toString())].toString());
    list.add(map);
  }
}
```

I'm getting conversion error at for (TraderTransaction trader : traderlist.GridRecords).

My Json data look like,

```
{
   "Messages":"RESULTS_RETRIEVAL_SUCCESSFULL",
   "OperationResult":0,
   "ResultData":{
      "GridRecords":[
         {
            "AddedBy":"Distributor-9787457361-Rathinavel",
            "AddedTime":"2013-04-12T16:26:24.0140117",
            "AmountPaid":0.0,
            "AmountRecieved":10000.0,
            "ClosingBalance":10000.0,
            "Narration":null,
            "OtherPartyAccountNo":"0102849015327675",
            "Status":2,
            "TransType":2,
            "TransactId":"TDRF483679051236"
         },
         {
            "AddedBy":"Distributor-9787457361-Rathinavel",
            "AddedTime":"2013-04-12T16:20:54.8681857",
            "AmountPaid":0.0,
            "AmountRecieved":0.0,
            "ClosingBalance":0.0,
            "Narration":null,
            "OtherPartyAccountNo":"0102849015327675",
            "Status":0,
            "TransType":2,
            "TransactId":"TDRF706925413802"
         }
      ],
      "Totalrecords":2
   },
   "UpdateAvailable":"0"
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? please provide stacktrace.

Comment: I'm getting error like can not convert class on  for (TraderTransaction trader : traderlist.GridRecords)

Comment: You should probably not use JSON for this. In general, it's not powerful enough to represent Java classes. You might get problems when you have circular references (e.g. A includes a B object and vice versa). My suggestion is to switch to XML. XStream worked good for me; also, it returned better error messages when e.g. failing with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to parse your JSON, I'd use a slightly different strategy. As you seem to be interested in parsing only the "ResultData", I'd create classes to *wrap* the response, very similar to those you have already created, namely:

```
public class Response {
  @SerializedName("ResultData")
  public ResultData resultData;
}
```

and,

```
public class ResultData {
  @SerializedName("GridRecords")
  public List<GridRecord> gridRecords;
  @SerializedName("Totalrecords")
  public int totalrecords;
}
```

and,

```
public class GridRecord {
  @SerializedName("AddedTime")
  public String addedTime;
  @SerializedName("TransactId")
  public String transactId;
  //other fields...
}
```

and other classes if necessary...

Then, in order to parse your JSON reponse, you just have to do:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Response data = gson.fromJson(responseString, Response.class);
```

and you'll be able to access any field, for example:

```
data.resultData.gridRecords.transactId;
```

*Note 1*: If you are interested in more fields of the JSON response, you just have to add more fields to your *wrap* classes, according to the JSON response...

*Note 2*: I've changed the type of `addedTime` to `String`, instead of `Date` because it throws an exception for unparseable date. Anyway I usually leave the types in the `Response` objects as simple `String` and then in the class from where I retrieve the response, I do the correct formatting while creating my objects, for example, when you put the values in your `Map`...

*Note 3*: The use of the annotation `@SerializedName` is interesting to separate the name of a field in the JSON response and in your app, in order to follow Java naming conventions, which your attributes are not following...

*Note 4*: You shouldn't use `public` attributes in your classes. It's more recommendable to use `private/protected` attributes and their correspondent `getters` and `setters`...